# In a Banach Space, when is $\sum |T(x_n)| < \infty$ for every sequence where $\sum x_i$ converges?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Given a Banach space $X$, and an operator $T \in X^*$, when does it hold that
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty |T(x_n)| < \infty$$
for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ such that $\sum_1^\infty x_n$ converges? As @Conrad points out, there is the trivial counter-example of the identity map on $X = \mathbb C$.

Note that I am *not* requiring absolute convergence of the $\sum x_i$. The problem would be trivial otherwise.

Context: I am a novice at Banach space theory, and this problem came up when I was studying another problem. In particular, fix a measurable space $(X,\mathcal M)$, and let $S$ be the Banach space of all bounded $\mathcal M$-measurable functions $f : X \to \mathbb C$ equipped with the uniform norm. What conditions must $T \in S^*$ obey for there to be a complex measure $\mu$ such that
$$Tf = \int f\,d\mu \quad \forall f \in S?$$
If $T$ were to have the magical property I described above, then this would be enough, because then one could define $\mu(E) = T\chi_E$. However, this only appears to work when $T$ has this property. To see this, by continuity, if $\{E_n\} \subset \mathcal M$ is a countable disjoint partition of a set $E \in \mathcal M$, then since $\chi_E = \sum \chi_{E_n}$ and the convergence is uniform (but notably not absolute w.r.t. the uniform norm), continuity dictates that
$$\mu(E) = T\chi_E = \sum_{i=1}^\infty T\chi_{E_i} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mu(E_i).$$
But the convergence is absolute only if
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty |T\chi_{E_i}| < \infty,$$
and this happens when $T$ satisfies this magical property. In particular this means that $\mu$ is a well-defined measure, and it is not too hard to work out that $Tf = \int f \,d\mu$.

Comment: what about if you take the Banach space just $\mathbb C$ and $T$ the identity

Comment: @Conrad Oh yes there is the trivial counter-example. I will revise my question now to make it hopefully more interesting. Under what conditions might this "magical property" hold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick any $x$ such that $Tx \neq 0$. Then take the sequence $x,-x,{1 \over 2}x , -{1 \over 2}x,..., {1 \over n}x, - {1 \over n}x,...$. Clearly the sum converges, but $\sum_k |T(x_k)| = \infty$.

Comment: Oh I see. So you are asserting that this property never holds in full generality. This was informative. Thank you for the simple counter-example!